# how to customize the PDF viewer toolbar in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, toolbar, pdf-viewer

Does anyone know where I can find information on customizing the toolbar of Chrome's built-in PDF viewer?

I have seen various posts concerning openParameters as defined by Adobe, but Chrome only seems to support the #page parameter.

I can't seem to find any Google API documentation on controlling the viewer from JavaScript, or via parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the Google PDF Viewer.